# Why description of my vue.js project URL is shown "noscript" in some application

Tags: vue.js, vue-meta

I have a vue.js project, when I put it's URL in some App,
I think it should be show the title and description below message box.

but it was show content of noscript tags, why?

I think I set title and description in my vue.js page correct, I used vue-meta package.

[image]

This is what shown in LINE, I want the title show in first line, and description show in second line.

[image]

And this is what shown in Instegram. Also, I think the first should be show the page title, but it's not.

[image]

Comment: Those services just fetch the initial HTML, they don't execute the Javascript in it.

Comment: how do I set the title and description in initial HTML?

Comment: On server side. These are the basics of SEO. If you're not sure a robot is able to render your scripts, you need to provide as much static HTML as needed. You can use Vue SSR or any other server rendering to produce meta in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @deceze already pointed out in the comments, services that try fetching a title and description for a website only fetch the initial HTML and don't execute JavaScript during the process. The `vue-meta` package, however, sets the title and meta tags only when executing JavaScript.

Assuming you are using `vue-cli`, there should be a file `public/index.html`, that is served as the initial HTML when requesting your application. In that file, you can easily adjust the `<title>` tag and add some `<meta>` tags to the `<head>` of the page.

You can also have a look at the Vue CLI documentation about the `index.html` file: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-index-file.

Comment: Thanks, I set the title and description in index.html, it's work!